# Jasmine spyOn $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, rootscope

**The problem:**
- using AngularJs
- given an implemented a service
- trying to test it with Jasmine

Here is how my service looks like:

```
angular.module('app.common').service('StateInterceptor',['$state','$rootScope',function($state,$rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){/*stuffs*/}

}
```

and here is how I'm trying to test whether the `$rootScope.$on` has been called:

```
describe("Testing StateInterceptor service", function(){
var $state, $rootScope, $scope, StateInterceptor;

beforeEach(module('app.common'));

beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
    spyOn($rootScope, "$on");

    $state = $injector.get("$state");

    StateInterceptor = $injector.get("StateInterceptor");
}));

it("WHEN created THEN it should call '$rootScope.$on' event listener", function(){
    //expect($rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled(); //not working neither
    expect($rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith("$stateChangeStart", jasmine.any(Function));
});
```

What I've got is an error message, saying:

> Expected spy $on to have been called with... (blabla) but it was never
>   called.

I've tried almost everything like:
- creating rootscope in this was: `$rootScope = $rootScope.$new();`
- spying `$rootScope.$on` like in this way: `spyOn($rootScope.prototype, "$on")`

but neither was working.
Do anybody know how to test it in the right way?

## Edit1:

the original code seems to working so I've pasted here the exactly code that I have.
So my service looks like exactly that:

```
angular.module('app.common').service('StateInterceptor',['$state','$rootScope',function($state,$rootScope){
    var self = this;
    self.bootstrapped = false;
    self.changeStart = [];


    self.init = function(){
        if(!self.bootstrapped){
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                /*staffs*/
                }
            );
        }
    }
    self.bootstrapped = true;

    self.init();
    return self;
}]);
```

Edit2:

I've put a few console.log to see how the code executed:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
    spyOn($rootScope, "$on");

    $state = $injector.get("$state");

    StateInterceptor = $injector.get("StateInterceptor");
}));
```

And for the code for the first line within self.init function:

```
console.log("init runs");
```

And the result is:
'init runs'
'before'
'after'

Strange! Any idea why is that?

Comment: Tried to replicate it here based on your code and it seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/oTJ8ZTHsKqCAzx7H4juU?p=preview

Comment: you right, check my update above

Comment: Is that the exact code? Cause there are syntax errors.

Comment: sorry, there are stuffs in he listener of course. I might deleted more than I wanted. Check now.

Comment: but I guess the problem will be that calling beforeEach(module("app.common")) is initializing the service as well and the code runs in this section before I inject the service into my test suite.

Comment: but am I right that every angularJS service is singleton? So there is no need to do that.

Comment: Still seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/jq4S436NOyZ7hZSnqmzS?p=preview

Comment: `beforeEach(module('app.common'))` will not initialize the service. It will not be created until someone asks for it (this instance will be cached and reused).

Comment: Thanks tasseKATT! So after I realized it should work, I made a bigger investigation within the module. There was another service which is using this service. So calling 'beforeEach(module("app.common"))' called the StateInterceptor before I could test it.

Comment: So I've made the changes and it works now!

Comment: If you create an answer, I can accept it as a solution, because  you helped me figuring out the cause.

Comment: You're welcome :) I think it's better if you post an answer yourself describing what the issue was since I never really gave the actual solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call $broadcast for "$stateChangeStart" event, it should automatically comes in $on().

Comment: He wants to test that the service sets up the event listener, not that `$on` is called when `$broadcast` is fired.

Comment: but $broadcast is dispatching events while $on is listenting on it, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks a lot for **tasseKATT** for helping me out. He was the guy who lead me to the solution.

The problem was that I had an another function in this module which run immediately as I inject the module in my test suite with 'beforeEach(module("app.common"))'.

Here is how the other function looked like:

```
angular.module('app.common').run(function($q,StateInterceptor,$modal){
  //stuffs, but pls notice that it injects the StateInterceptor which caused the problem!
});
```

So I've put this out to another module and make it as a dependency to the other one.